# Problems storing correlation in matrix using rcorr from the Hmisc package

Tags: r, hmisc

I want to calculate the p-values for the correlation of two matricies using `Hmisc`.  I am having a problem storing the resulting p-values in a matrix:

```
library("Hmisc")
x <- as.matrix(read.table("tmp01"))
y <- as.matrix(read.table("tmp02"))
P <- matrix(0, ncol(x), ncol(y))

for (i in 1:ncol(x)) {
    for(j in 1:ncol(y)) {
        P[i,j] <- rcorr(x[,i],y[,j])
    }
}
```

Returns this error:

```
Error in P[i, j] <- rcorr(x[, i], y[, j]) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Comment: `rcorr` returns a list, so you'd need to subset out just the p-value, for example with something along the lines of  `rcorr(x[, i], y[, j])$P[1,2]`

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help!